# Navigating pages within a Pdf dynamically

Tags: iphone, pdf, xcode4, uiwebview, ios5

I would like to be able to navigate a large Pdf file (275 pages) by either going to a specific page or moving from page to page dynamically. I have looked at using 
pdfNavigateController.scrollPosition which works okay with IOS 4.2 and lower but not with IOS 5. If anyone has ony other suggestions that works with IOS 4 and 5, I would be really grateful.

Comment: For detailed description http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039367/navigating-a-pdf-using-uiwebview-not-working-in-ios-5/8296107#8296107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered via another similar question I posted. The reason it does not work with IOS5 is that IOS 5 does not support javascript. You can navigate through your Pdf using webView.scrollView instead using CGPointMake(x, y)